# How to use breadcrumbs in jsp code used in below code...please help me

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Please help me how to use bread crumbs in these hyperlinks so that they sohow tracker

```
String cat_code= fetch.getCat_code(); %>
<% if(P_list!=null && P_list.size()>0) { for(int i=0;i
    <P_list.size();i++) { b=( Bean)P_list.get(i); %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:getSubCategory('<%=b.getCat_code() %>') "><%=b.getCat_parent(%></a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:getSubCategory('<%=b.getCat_code() %>')"><%=b.getCat_name() %></a>
            </td>
            <td><a href="javascript:getSubCategory('<%=b.getCat_code() %>')"><%=b.getCat_code() %></a>
            </td>
```

We get hyperlinks of all parent & their childs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945

Answer (score 0):

As you have atagged you question with jquery, I suggest that you use a jquery breadcrumb plugin such as 
http://www.comparenetworks.com/developers/jqueryplugins/jbreadcrumb.html